# IconUrl asset URL in vuejs JavaScript code

Tags: vue.js, path, vuejs2, leaflet

I'm having trouble trying to create a icon in Leaflet using Vuejs. It doesn't show the icon and I don't know how to fix the path. I have tried all the paths I can think of:

- `assets/leaf-green.png`
- `/assets/leaf-green.png`
- `../assets/leaf-green.png`
- `../../assets/leaf-green.png`
- `src/assets/leaf-green.png`
- `../src/assets/leaf-green.png`
- `../../src/assets/leaf-green.png`

Code (**Map.vue**):

```
const greenIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: "assets/leaf-green.png",
  iconSize: [38, 95],
  iconAnchor: [22, 94],
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
});
```

Project structure:

[image]

DevTools Network tab shows that it tries to load this url:
http://localhost:8080/assets/leaf-green.png

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the Network tab in chrome development tools to see where it tries to load it from?

Comment: Network tries to load: http://localhost:8080/assets/leaf-green.png and /assets/... didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/assets` is not served. The images become `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...YII="` strings.

**Solution:** use relative path.

For example, say you have the following folder structure:

```
- src
  +- assets
     - myImage.png
  +- components
     - MyComponent.vue
```

If you want to reference the image in `MyComponent.vue`, the path sould be `../assets.myImage.png`

Check this demo codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/610zwq4o6w?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

## Using from JavaScript

Use `require('../assets/myImage.png')`

Comment: can you tell me how? I've tried ../assets/leaf-green.png and ../../assets/leaf-green.png but doens't work either

Comment: I can load images with relative path in the template part, but I cannot use that same url in the JS part :S

Comment: Use `require()`

Comment: This just did not work for me. With my learning curve the one word hint of 32-goldmedal acdcjunior 'Use require()' was not applicable. Ok, I did not give up and created another answer which I hope helps faster now for people of my knowledge level of vue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, these up to date already exisiting did not yield me straight to a working solution. I checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866199/845117 to get the correct hint which is:

```
 const greenIcon = L.icon({
     iconUrl: require('./assets/leaf-green.png'),
     iconSize: [38, 95],
     iconAnchor: [22, 94],
     popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
 });
```

Whether it is `./assets`, `../assets` or even something like `../../assets` depends on your structure where you place your *.vue*-components.
It is relative to the path from where you want to call/reference it.
As I understood you always have to start with at least one dot.