# Vue.js: Leaflet-Marker is not visible

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

I'm using vue.js together with Leaflet. Unfortunately the marker on the map is not visible, but the tooltip of the marker is visible.
[The location of the marker is set to London.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW7cK.png)
The map is a component (Map.vue):

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
  import L from 'leaflet';
  import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';


  export default {
    name: 'test-map',
    mounted () {
      var map = L.map(this.$el).setView([51.5076, -0.1276], 4);
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: ['a','b','c']
      }).addTo(map);

      var loc = [51.5076, -0.1276];
      var marker = L.marker(loc).addTo(map);
      marker.bindTooltip("Here is the marker");
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  div {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

And my App looks like that (App.vue):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <test-map></test-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestMap from './components/Map.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    TestMap
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  #app {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
```

I really don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems like you have to require the pngs in your main.js ?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
   iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
   iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
   shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
});

new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: Hey, if you're still waiting for it. Here you go. It's related to moduler loading(like webpack in vuejs) https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968

Comment: Note for those that can't make this work. `require` returns an object and you'll need to return `.default` to get the string. EX: `require('location').default` I'm unsure of when this changed.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, I followed many tutorials in order to solve it but with no result

https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/
https://korigan.github.io/Vue2Leaflet/#/components/l-icon/

For my case (with a locally installed component) the solution consists of two steps :

1.
Putting these lignes of code :

```
import { Icon }  from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

// this part resolve an issue where the markers would not appear
delete Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
    iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
    shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
});
```

2.
Use a "require" before the desired custom picture

```
 data: function() {
    return {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: require("relative_or_absolute_path"),
        iconSize: [38, 95],
        iconAnchor: [22, 94]
      })
    };
  }
```

I hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I had kind of the same issue too. Custom marker wouldn't show properly (everything else worked). Like I could have the tooltip/popup, so marker was selectable but invisible.
Now I solved it by importing the png directly in the component.
In case it could help.

Map.vue component

template

```
<l-marker>
    <l-icon :icon-url="customMarker"></l-icon>
</l-marker>
```

and in script:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import {
    LMarker
    LIcon
} from 'vue2-leaflet';

// this is what was missing
import customMarker from '../yourDirectory/customMarker.png'

    // The following is the official VueLeaflet fix
    // to solve issue with default marker icon missing (webpack messing around)
    // https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/quickstart/#marker-icons-are-missing

    import {
        Icon
    } from 'leaflet';

    delete Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
    Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
        iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
        iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
        shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
    });
    // End of fix

export default {
    data() {
          customMarker
    }
}
```